# How to config remember me in jasig cas 5.1.x

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, jasig

I successed in cas 4.2.x via this document:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Configuring-LongTerm-Authentication.html
many changes in cas 5.1.x ,now I want to upgrade to 5.1.x . Readed many documents,but still confused. like . where is `<var name="credential" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredential"/>` etc.

I don't know how to config it . any one master it? or tell me the document where it is . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked about the document and its location, the guide is here

https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configuring-LongTerm-Authentication.html

Follow the guide and adjust your settings appropriately. There is no need for xml.